# "not exists" does not exclude row from table

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to exclude certain rows from my result but can not get it to work.

What I am trying:

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM SubCategory 
WHERE not exists
(SELECT null FROM SubCategory WHERE subCategory = 'Games')
ORDER BY views DESC
```

I want it to exclude rows with value "Games". However when I run this it returns nothing.

Im using Microsoft SQL server 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get what you're trying to do. Your query will return rows, only if none exist which match the criteria. If that's what you want, then yes, what you have should worked.

From your description, though, it sounds like you'd be looking for more like this:

```
SELECT TOP 5 *
FROM SubCategory 
WHERE subcategory <> 'Games'
ORDER BY views DESC
```

Beyond that, I'm just not sure what you're going for.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't knwo I had gotten it so wrong. From what I could find online they were doing it like this. But your version works

Comment: @MrCharli3 Ah, cool. Yeah, this is a standard way of doing it. Glad I could help. Is there anything else I can clear up?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use NOT EXISTS clause, a simple filter on WHERE clause will give you expected results.

Try This.

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM SubCategory
WHERE SubCategory <> 'Games'
ORDER BY [views] DESC
```